# How to read connection string from key vault for Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault

Here is how I instantiate the client in my `Configure` method:

```
services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusClient>(x => new ServiceBusClient(configuration.GetSection("ServiceBus:ConnectionString").Value, serviceBusClientOptions));
```

And this how my appsettings looks like:

```
{
  "ServiceBus:ConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=MyVaultName;SecretName=MySecretName)"
}
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
The connection string used for an Service Bus client must specify the Service Bus namespace host and either a Shared Access Key (both the name and value) OR a Shared Access Signature to be valid. (Parameter 'connectionString'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi havij; have you double-checked that there is a keyvault called "MyVaultName", with a secret called "MySecretName", which contains a valid service bus connection string?

Comment: @VinceBowdren yup I do have that secret with a valid value.

Comment: You can double check - that on startup of your project, the KeyVault is set up as a configuration provider. This way .Net knows to read config from the key vault

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a **managed identity** for you application and added **access policies** such that your app can GET this secret value from key vault?

Check out the official documentaion for this here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

[image]

**Also on a side note**, have you tried directly adding the secret value as the appsetting value instead of referencing it from KV and see if that worked? (if yes then definitely its a permissions issue and NOT a problem with your C# app code.